# Why do we need to add proton and neutron as same number to figure out the weight of it?

Tags: atomic-physics, physical-chemistry

For example, the Carbon is number 6. That means it has 6 protons. If we add the 6 neutron the total is 12 and we call it carbon 12. 1 neutron and 1 proton equal as the 1 atomic mass unit. That means the carbon's weight is 12 and real it is 12.011.

But why we have to add proton and neutron as same number.

Comment: we are counting baryons. in isotopic spin they are two different up and down states .

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of points we need to make clear in your question.

Firstly the weight of a ${}^{12}\text{C}$ atom is not $12.011$ amu. If you take some random sample of carbon it is a mixture of $98.9$% ${}^{12}\text{C}$ and $1.1$% ${}^{13}\text{C}$ (and a vanishingly small amount of ${}^{14}\text{C}$). The figure of $12.011$ amu is the average atomic weight of the atoms in the mixture. The atomic weight of ${}^{12}\text{C}$ is in fact exactly $12$ amu because that is how an [atomic mass unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_atomic_mass_unit) is defined i.e. one twelth of the mass of a ${}^{12}\text{C}$ atom.

However you are correct that in general atoms do not have an atomic weight that is an integer, though this isn't just due to the difference in the proton and neutron weights. For example a hydrogen atom has just a single proton while a carbon atom has 6 protons and 6 neutrons. Since neutrons are heavier than protons you might expect a hydrogen atom to be lighter than 1/12th of a carbon atom, but in fact it is heavier at $1.007825$ amu so twelve hydrogen atoms would actually weigh $12.0939$ amu or about a percent heavier than a ${}^{12}\text{C}$ atom.

The difference in weights is due to the nuclear binding energy of the nucleus, also called the mass deficit or [mass defect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Mass_defect). For reasons that take some thought the effect of the binding energy is to decrease the mass of the nucleus.

Anyhow, the bottom line is that when it comes to atomic weights we do not simply count the number of nucleons. While the difference in the proton and neutron weights plays some role the binding energy is just as important, and in practice atomic weights an an isotopic average anyway.

Finally, let me pick up on a point mentioned by Anna in a comment. In a nucleus protons and neutrons are in effect different versions of the same particle because they related by a symmetry called [isospin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isospin). That means there is some sense in just counting the total numbers of nucleons.

Answer (score 0):

We don't multiply number of neutrons by two to get atomic mass, this is wrong. 
First, the mass of the nucleus is a mass of the proton-neutron system, which is actually smaller than the sum of masses of neutrons and protons at rest due to smaller potential energy of that system.

How many neutrons and protons in a nucleus is determined by the stability of the nucleus. Like with electron shells, there is similar theory about nuclear shells. There are several stable configurations of the nuclei and many of them have more neutrons then protons. One chemical element has several variations of its nucleus.

Look up isotopes. Even Wiki has a decent explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotope

For instance hydrogen has two stable isotopes, protium (proton) and deuterium(proton+neutron) with atomic mass 1 and two, respectively. All naturally occurring elements and their abundance is taken into account and an averaged mass is calculated. So when you take a glass of water from ocean, it will have some protium and some deuterium